# C++ pointer and stack memory management 

Tags: c++

I have a General question about memory management in my c++ code. The compiler complains that there is a potential memory leak when I replace a pointer to an object with an new pointer to an object that I have initialized dynamically on the stack. Example:

```
int* foo(int* h){
 int* b = new int(5);
 b = h;  //Memory leak here. How do I delete b without creating a dangling pointer?
 return b;
}
```

I then use this function to change the state of a pointer

`int i = 1;
int*  c = &i;
foo(c);`

So my question is I have a class that has a function similar to the one above.
when can I delete b from the foo function?

```
delete b;
```

would this go into the destructor (which would not help me, as I am using function foo loads of times. so the heap would get used up possibly....? )

If I have not provided enough info above. Please let me know.

Comment: Let's start with the basics: your function `foo` does not modify the value pointed to by its parameter at all. What is it supposed to do exactly?

Comment: `foo(c);` does nothing with `c`

Comment: to be honest i didn't understand your question.. but there is a risk of memory leak, for example: foo(new int); here an int will be leaked when u call foo

Comment: The compiler is correct that this could be a memory leak. Are you losing the address of an allocated object when you change the pointer? It seems convoluted and error prone to me. Is there a better way to accomplish it?

Comment: sorry guys i made a boo boo in my example. How about now

Comment: In your case (seeing code snippets like this), I would forget about new and delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a general question, my preferred general approach would be to use a smart pointer handled using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) within your class.

The smart pointer encapsulates the raw pointer, and handles required memory management for you - when your class is destructed, whatever pointer value is held therein at the time will get cleaned up without you having to manually delete it.  When you assign a new value to the smart pointer, it auto-deletes the existing value for you, if any.

[boost::scoped_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) as a class member ought to work well for you here.

There also seems to be confusion here about what's on the stack and what's on the heap.  You will not use up the stack simply because you are calling `foo` over and over (unless you recurse into `foo` unbounded, in which case you will eventually run out of stack space).  Your local variable `b` is on the stack, but it points to memory that is allocated using `new` on the heap.  When you exit `foo`, the stack is reset for the calling function - the stack memory used for `b` is now available for the next function it calls - but you still need to retain ownership (and eventually release) the heap memory to which `b` pointed.

EDIT: some sample code should clarify smart pointer approach

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() {}  // no explicit init for myPointer needed
  ~MyClass() {} // frees up any pointer held in myPointer, no explicit delete needed

  void Foo(int* c)
  {
     myPointer.reset(c);  // releases any existing value, takes ownership of c
  }

private:
  boost::scoped_ptr<int> myPointer;  // initially empty
};
```

Comment: Hi Steve. The last paragraph is the question that I am asking. Just never formulated it well above. How would I go about releasing memory from the heap without c becoming a dangling pointer? Or would this not happen? Thanks again!

Comment: I've added some code to clarify, hope this helps. Smart pointers and RAII are a key part of improving your C++ productivity and code quality.  it's important to understand what's happening under the covers, of course, and how you would do it manually using `new/delete` as in your original question.

Comment: Thanks steve this is great! Is boost part of the STL or do I need a library?? This is very C# ish

Comment: Boost is a separate set of libraries but some of these smart pointers are in the newer compilers, eg. Visual C++ in VS2010. You could also use `std::auto_ptr` although it's not as elegant as the Boost ones. In VS2010 you would use `std::unique_ptr` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410601.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to replace the pointer's value with a new pointer allocated in the function, I would recommend using a reference:

```
void SomeClass::foo(int*& h)
{
  delete h;
  h = new int(5);
}
```

Of course, this will break if you call it with a pointer to an `int` which is *not* on the heap, since you can't `delete` it in that case. So don't do that.

Comment: Hi unwind. I have changed my function above? where would the delete b go? After I set h in the function or would this cause h to be a dangling pointer?